# Regex - Prevent repeated characters

Tags: php, regex, validation

I've spent hours and hours trying to solve this.

Here is my Regex string:
 `^(?=.{4})(?!.{32})[a-zA-Z0-9_]+((\.(-\.)*-?|-(\.-)*\.?)                   [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$` -
You can test it [here](http://regexr.com?32ffh)

Here is what I tried to acomplish (username validation):

1. string length range -> OK
2. letters, numbers, _ - . allowed (- and . disallowed at begining and or end of username) -> OK
3. need to prevent repeated characters (over 5 characters in line) -> **need help!**

Comment: Please give examples of strings you want to match which are currently failing. It's very difficult to tell what "permit repeated characters over 5 characters inline" means. Are you saying you want to match "aaaaa" but not "aaaa"?

Comment: you need to *permit* repeated characters or *prevent*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
^(?=.{4})(?!.{32})(?!.*(.)\1{4})\w[\w.-]+\w$
```

Use another (negative) lookahead to take care of the third condition. This one will make sure that there is no character, that is followed by itself 4 times.

I also simplified your character classes by using `\w` which represents `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Also, as F.J pointed out, you can combine the first two lookaheads into one:

```
^(?=.{4,31}$)(?!.*(.)\1{4})\w[\w.-]+\w$
```

Comment: +1, This is clearer than my version which does the repeated character check as it is matching, instead of as its own lookahead.

Comment: Dude, you rock! Thank you so much; now I wish to bite myself ... wasted hours being shy to ask :-(

Comment: No problem :). If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the green checkmark) to show others, who might find this question in the future, what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
^(?=.{4,31}$)(?![-.])(?:(?!(.)\1{4})[-.\w])+(?<![-.])$
```

Example: http://regexr.com?32ffq

This assumes that you actually meant **prevent** repeated characters, instead of permit.